# Jquery slide right and back

Tags: jquery

Please look at [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/eTNW7/) on jsfiddle. The blue thing is supposed to slide right and back. 
Help is certainly welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data` to store the `slide_out` variable in the element, and change `0px` to just `0`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#right_column").click(function(){
    if(!$(this).data('slide_out')){
      $("#right_column").animate({left:0},"slow");
      $(this).data('slide_out', true);
      }
    if($(this).data('slide_out')){
      $("#right_column").animate({left:-140},"slow");
      $(this).data('slide_out', false);
      }
  });
});
```

Look at it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qxU4v/).

Comment: Thanks so much! I did tweak it a little bit but you gave me a big boost.

Answer (score 0):

Your referencing slideout like a php variable. Not a javascript one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var slide_out
      $("#right_column").click(function(){
        if(slide_out){
          $("#right_column").animate({left:0px},"slow");
          slide_out=true;
          }
        if(slide_out){
          $("#right_column").animate({left:-140px},"slow");
          slide_out=false;
          }
      });
    });
```